# How to create a user registration system that all users have their own account page after they logged in with node.js and mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web

I am here to ask for some advice for my thesis project.

Well, I am working on my thesis project. I plan to build a community website that allows the user to create content. To be more detailed, after the user logs in to their account, they will find a page that allows them to create a post. After they create the post and submit the form, the post will be the push to the website.

Each user has their own account. Inside their account, they could create and submit content. My question is: I don't know the method to build this user system that allows each user to have their own account page after they log in. If anyone could provide a method or resources, I would really appreciate. I've googled for a long time for tutorials and methods, but most stuff are about how to create a user login and registration. I think this won't be so complex, but I just could not find good resources. BTW, I think I just need minimal security for this user system since it's a school project.

Any advice or resources would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You are saying it's a thesis project then later on say it's a school project. :)

Comment: Well, let me clarify, it's my thesis project at the university, so it's a school project, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the few steps by which you can setup the architecture of your prject.

- After successfull login, create a routes for user where user related features is render. For example, after loggin, page redirected to localhost:3000/users/dashboard. All User personal UI render here. **NOTE** This page is only accessible when user loggedin successfully, if not and user try to open the page through URL, then kindly redirect it to login page.
- By default localhost:3000/ is the main page where all users post/content will show

Comment: Thanks for sharing your design. It really helps!

Comment: It is advisable to ask a question when you have done some research and homework. It will be easier for others also to understand your efforts.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.